# Codeigniter: Changing SQL query in model leads to a "failed to open stream" warning. Testing with a simple select * query works, however

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Database: MySQL version 5.6 hosted on remote server
Codeigniter version: 3.0.6 on localhost
PHP version: 5.5.9

I am working with a model, trying to build up a specific query and pass the result to my controller. Here's what they look like:

Model 1 (this works):

```
public function view_offer(){
    $sql = "SELECT Offer.OfferID, Outlet.OutletName, Offer.MaxSurge, Offer.OfferSurge, Offer.OfferStart, Offer.OfferStop, Offer.OfferQuantity, Offer.OfferSold, Offer.OfferStatus
            FROM OfferDetails Offer
            LEFT JOIN RestaurantOutlet Outlet 
            ON Offer.OutletID = Outlet.OutletID";
    //$query = $this->db->query('sql');
    $query = $this->db->get('OfferDetails');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Model 2 (This doesn't work):

```
public function view_offer(){
    $sql = "SELECT Offer.OfferID, Outlet.OutletName, Offer.MaxSurge, Offer.OfferSurge, Offer.OfferStart, Offer.OfferStop, Offer.OfferQuantity, Offer.OfferSold, Offer.OfferStatus
            FROM OfferDetails Offer
            LEFT JOIN RestaurantOutlet Outlet 
            ON Offer.OutletID = Outlet.OutletID";
    $query = $this->db->query('sql');
    //$query = $this->db->get('OfferDetails');
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Controller (This doesn't change while changing model):

```
public function running_offers(){
    print_r($this->offers->view_offer());
}
```

The difference between the 2 models is that one is a simple "SELECT * FROM OfferDetails;" while the other involves a table join and selected return of columns (check the commented out lines in each code segment).

For model 1, things go smoothly. I am able to query the database and print_r puts the array contents on screen.

Model 2 does not work. The warning that I get for model 2 is quite bizarre:

> Warning:
>   include(/var/www/html/admin/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/var/www/html/admin/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning:
>   include(/var/www/html/admin/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/var/www/html/admin/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

My localhost is an ubuntu machine. To simplify matters related to permissions, I have done the following:

chown -R my-user-id:www-data /var/www/html
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

Googling the warning messages returned, I find references to change my php.ini file. Why? How can changing the query that will anyway get run in MySQL need me to change my php.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

`failed to open stream` error showed, because not available files, which used for showing error messages (`error_php.php`).